# What do these inserts from a reducing tee do?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, kitchen-sink

A reducing tee underneath the kitchen sink is leaking small amounts of water. I'm planning to replace it. I've just purchased a replacement reducing tee, but I'm wondering what is the purpose of those inserts that go into hoses do? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are to support the inside of poly tubing. The tubing is too soft by its self to provide a proper compression seal.  The inserts then are used to support the tubing.

Comment: pipe stiffeners.  sharkbite/push fit connections use them on pex too...  though you can remove them if doing push fit to copper.